# assign var to image name ( php )

Tags: php

I am trying to play with php, I aint very good. But I figured its about time I started playing with it

What I have is say a page called ascr

Its filename is acsr.php

I have created a global php include, so I can play with different vars and include them dynamically.

So I have made a var called $shorttag = "acsr";

On my page I would like to use that shorttag to fire images and classes etc.

So for an image I want to display

```
img src="/img/<?php $shorttag; ?>.jpg"
```

and in other places perhaps,

```
div class="<?php $shorttag; ?>"
```

Is this the CORRECT way of doing stuff like this ?

//////////////////////////////////////

Example.

say I have folder with image in it called acsr.jpg

On my dynamic page I want to echo that image, but instead of using filename, I want to pull it in based on my php var , in this case its called $shorttag so essentially, $shorttag=acsr , and therefore I can spew out something like:

```
<?php $shorttag; ?>.jpg
```

( code above more than likely wrong )

But the result gives me ascr.jpg

Comment: really? so say I want to display image called acsr.jpg how can I replace the acsr with php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `echo` it so it is actually output.

```
div class="<?php echo $shorttag; ?>"

img src="/img/<?php echo $shorttag; ?>.jpg"
```

If PHP is configured to [use `short_open_tag`](https://www.php.net/manual/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) (which is not usually recommended since it may be turned off on some servers)

```
img src="/img/<?= $shorttag ?>.jpg"
```

The rules change for PHP 5.4 and later, where you can use `<?= ?>` without having to turn on `short_open_tag`:

> This directive also affected the shorthand `<?=` before PHP 5.4.0, which is identical to `<? echo`. Use of this shortcut required `short_open_tag` to be on. Since PHP 5.4.0, `<?=` is always available.

Comment: Ahh you saviour, yes we had turned shorttags ( php shorttags ) that is off. Bad filename in this case, leading to confusion. Will add the echo, MY BAD !

Answer (score 1):

Your examples is missing a way to echo out the value. You can either use `echo` like what Michael suggested, or use the syntax `<?= $shorttag ?>`.

Additionally, in your examples, you will be creating an image at `/img/acsr.jpg` and attaching a class called `acsr` to that div. If that is what you want, then yes, you're on the right track. Otherwise, you will need to explain more of what you wish to accomplish.

Comment: thankyou, I had forgot we had the shorttag ( in php ) switched off ! Have added echo now and all good.

Answer (score 1):

You're basically doing what I did with "pid" and "sid" (i.e., http://mysite.com/?pid=main_page&sid=sub_context) right?

You'll have to make sure your pages are protected from user tampering by ensuring your parameter values adhere to a standard (ex., regex replace all but a-zA-Z_- with ""). As for classes, you'd do best to avoid having them rely on a page id for styling. Make your styles global in nature.

Comment: hmm , I hadnt even looked at it from this angle. Goodonya. Im far too inexperienced to play with the regex part but will muddle thru, as the results are sweet as. Then will look at your aspect